# get_field within hyperlink wont return field

Tags: php, html, video, hyperlink, popover

I am trying to display a popover video where part of the hyperlink is contained in the field `single_video_url`.

*My code:*

```
 <a href="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/"-?php $video = get_field (' single_video_url '); ?>" ?popover=true" class="wistia-popover[height=360,playerColor=F36F36,width=640]">
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here? It works if I replace the get field part with the actual hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="http://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/<?php $video = get_field (' single_video_url '); ?>popover=true" class="wistia-popover[height=360,playerColor=F36F36,width=640]">sample text</a>
```

use this code

Comment: Thanks, I added a '?' to the field and it seemed to do the trick:)